# unable to watch linq extension methods of Dictionary<int, Type> in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have `Dictionary<int, Type> msgTypes` in a class library targeting .NET 4.6.

This DLL is imported into a unity project with the .NET framework set to 4.x.

I am trying to debug the code in the DLL, so i also imported the PDB into unity, and attached VS2017 to the unity process using the unity tools.

I have the following line of code:

```
...msgTypes.First(x => x.Value == typeof(TIn)).Key...
```

This has been causing errors in unity because it says it can't find a match...

The image below is what I see when I step to that particular line:
[image: debug watch]

Is there a problem with linq support in unity? What does "Node not supported" mean? What am I doing wrong?

Here is the whole method in case it is of interest:

```
private Dictionary<int, Type> msgTypes = new Dictionary<int, Type>();

public byte[] Prepare<TIn>(TIn message)
{
    var content = msgSerializer.Serialize(message);

        byte[] payload = new byte[content.Length + LengthPrefixWidth + IdPrefixWidth];

        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)content.Length + IdPrefixWidth), 0, payload, 0, LengthPrefixWidth);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)msgTypes.First(x => x.Value == typeof(TIn)).Key), 0, payload, LengthPrefixWidth, IdPrefixWidth);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(content, 0, payload, LengthPrefixWidth + IdPrefixWidth, content.Length);

        return payload;
    }
```

P.S. the dictionary is populated, the code is long so I didn't post it, but there *are* values in the dictionary and specifically, the one I am looking for is also present.

EDIT

I noticed that watching `TIn` produces the error:

> The identifier `TIn` is not in the scope

EDIT 2

This code works if I change:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)msgTypes.First(x => x.Value == typeof(TIn)).Key), 0, payload, LengthPrefixWidth, IdPrefixWidth);
```

to:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)msgTypes.First(x => x.Value == typeof(StatisticsRequest)).Key), 0, payload, LengthPrefixWidth, IdPrefixWidth);
```

This tells me that something is wrong with unity's handling of generics. Also, there is no way to "watch" the generic `TIn`, according to VS, it does not exist... Something fishy with generics...

Comment: I would also suggest using `FirstOrDefault` rather than `First`.

Comment: @mjwills Yes, as i mentioned, I have visual studio tools for unity installed. I agree with `FirstOrDefault` but I had changed it to just `First` while trying to get the watch to work.